# Почему не выполняется код Python в cmd

Tags: cmd, командная-строка

Решил начать изучать python. После установки, для проверки я ввёл команду в командную строку. Но ничего не выходит, почему?

[image: e-cmd]

Comment: Вам нужно сначало открыть саму среду python. Просто напишите `python`

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить перед заданием вопроса в следующий раз

Comment: `python`/`python3`, `print('hello world')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы по всей видимости в командной строке не использовали сам Python, т.е. не ввели нужные данные для начала работы. Если вы установили Python, то у вас с ним вместе должна идти среда разработки - "IDLE"(попробуйте ввести в поиске Windows). Для начала среда вполне сойдёт.

Comment: IDLE - это мягко говоря не самый лучший выбор редактора/IDE. Ни для начала, ни для продолжения.

Answer (score 0):

В обычной консоли нельзя писать код, для этого есть редакторы кода или интерактивная консоль питона.

Comment: можно, я писал код питона в консоли, написал python, нажал Enter, и после этого я могу выполнять код питона прямо в консоли написывая текст

Comment: Рекомендую читать ответы до конца,  а не только первые три слова. Повторю текст из ответа:  в ОБЫЧНОЙ консоли.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сначала написать команду python, а потом писать тот код, который хочешь (на python естественно).

Вообще, код в командной строке не пишут, для этого есть IDE (текстовые редакторы), которые могут скомпилировать python код.
Например PyCharm

Comment: `для этого есть IDE (текстовые редакторы), которые могут скомпилировать python код. Например PyCharm` - ни редакторы, ни IDE не компилируют код.